# How to find which file text on my website's home page is located?

Tags: php, web

I want to know which file in the server a particular line of text on my website is in.

I have tried inspecting the element and also downloading the backup and searching for the string in the files. There are too many files to check them all.

The website is coachingadda.com and the text string is "Find Tutors for Science, Maths, Commerce, English and other subjects. Can't find a tutor? Post your very own tuition request"

Comment: `grep -R "Find Tutors for Science, Maths, Commerce, English and other subjects." *`

Comment: You may not be able to find it if the content is being served from a database or external resource.

Comment: Not from an external source, since no text is being fetched from outside my server

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on stack overflow itself, so answering it myself if somebody else needs it later.

Install Total Commander, Search (Alt+F7) for the text string inside the file directory. You'll find the file which contains the searched text string.